# Capture Up/Down Touches on a Button

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to capture the OnKeyUp event for a specific button. So I'm trying to capture all OnKeyUp events and filter for the one I want. Here is my code;

```
[Android.Runtime.Register("onKeyUp", "(ILandroid/view/KeyEvent;)Z", "GetOnKeyUp_ILandroid_view_KeyEvent_Handler")]  

public Boolean OnKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent bevent)
    {//do something
        return true;
    }
```

I run in debug mode and set a break point for the return true; line. After pressing buttons in the app, it never goes to the function. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For `Button` up/down touches implement `IOnTouchListener`

#### Button Example:

```
[Activity(Label = "MPAndroidChartTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity, Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListener
{
    int count = 1;
    Button button;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);

        button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
        button.SetOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (button == null)
            button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
        if (v == button)
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    Log.Debug("Ontouch", "Start Timer");
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                    Log.Debug("Ontouch", "Stop Timer");
                    break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

For a Key up/down Press:

Within your `Activity` override `OnKeyUp`

#### Entry Example:

```
public override bool OnKeyUp(Android.Views.Keycode keyCode, Android.Views.KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Android.Views.Keycode.C)
        Log.Debug("KeyPress", "C Keycode");
    return base.OnKeyUp(keyCode, e);
}
```

Comment: We both missed it. Your code works when I type in a edit field, but what I need is a buttonup. I have a radio app with some buttons. I want to detect when it's pushed and when it's released like a real radio. If it's held down more than 2 seconds I set the frequency. I was going to compare the time from buttondown to buttonup. However I don't see a buttondown or button downclick or buttonup. Is there such a function, or is there another way to do this.

Comment: @Dave : I added a up/down Button Example

Comment: This is what I want, but I'm receiving an error for line; </br>  button.SetOnTouchListener(this); I receive the error, "Can not convert from MPAndroidChartTest.MainAcitivity to Android.Views.View..IOnTouchListiner"

Comment: @Dave Look at my code sample, you have to add the `IOnTouchListener` interface to your `MainActivity`: `public class MainActivity : Activity, Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListener` Then the assignment of `this` to a `IOnTouchListiner` will be valid

Comment: Thanks, that did it. One other note, I have six buttons and I just added all six to the buttonx.SetOnTouchListener(this); and then checked v in the OnTouch routine to see which button was pressed, and the duration. That worked perfectly.